Probability of Christmas falling on a particular day of the week
What is the probability that Christmas (on a randomly chosen year) falls on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, &c.? Accounting for the leap years and the 400-year repeating cycle, I wrote a program to model this situation and my answers were:
Sunday 58/400
Monday 56/400
Tuesday 58/400
Wednesday 57/400
Thursday 57/400
Friday 58/400
Saturday 56/400
I verified my answers with my teacher, and they're correct, but I need to solve the problem on pen and paper, without empirically going through every case in a 400-year period. What would be a simple/subtle answer to this? Also, I need to prove most of the assumptions I make in my solution (such as the Gregorian calendar repeating every 400 years).
I found a solution online, and two Stack threads, but I can't really make much sense of it: https://people.missouristate.edu/lesreid/Sol04_0809.html
Thank you :D

Why wouldn't it be $1/7$?  What is special about one weekday over another?

Related: Distribution of days in a week on Christmas

@DavidG.Stork The calendar repeats every 400 years -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Description - and 400 is not a multiple of 7. For example, averaged over a whole 400 year cycle, the 13th of the month is more likely to be a Friday than any other day: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_the_13th#Distribution
